# Why does PropertyDescriptor return a property name with uppercase as first character?

Tags: java, javabeans

I'm obtaining an information about a class via

```
Introspector.getBeanInfo(this.getClass()).getPropertyDescriptors()
```

then getting the property's name by invoking `propery[i].getName()`.

Everything is fine if a property has no one-letter-part. For example, if a property has a name `personAddress` (meanwhile its getter/setter -> `getPersonAddress()`, `setPersonAddress(String personAddress)`), is's OK, `getName()` returns `personAddress`.

But if the property has a name `rPersonId` (`getRPersonId()`, `setRPersonId(Long rPersonId)`) then `getName()` returns "RPersonId", i.e. first letter has been capitalized! Why?

According to this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/FeatureDescriptor.html:

> `public String getName()`-> Gets the programmatic name of this feature.

So why does it return a name somehow related to its getter's or setter's name instead of the real name of the property?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually the documented behaviour.

First of all, property names are entirely located by discovering their getter and setter, and not by looking at the fields of the class. This is specified in paragraph 8.3 of the [Java Beans specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/):

> If we discover a matching pair of `get<PropertyName>` and `set<PropertyName>` methods that take and return the same type, then we regard these methods as defining a read-write property whose name will be `<propertyName>`.

So when you have the introspection of a class that contains `Long getRPersonId()` and `setRPersonId(Long)`, a property can be extracted from it. The name of the property generally follows from lower-casing the first letter, and keeping the rest unchanged. But this is not always the case, the exact rule is in paragraph 8.8:

> Thus when we extract a property or event name from the middle of an existing Java name, we normally convert the first character to lower case. However to support the occasional use of all upper-case names, we check if the first two characters of the name are both upper case and if so leave it alone. So for example:
>
> - `FooBah` becomes `fooBah`
> - `Z` becomes `z`
> - `URL` becomes `URL`
>
> We provide a method `Introspector.decapitalize` which implements this conversion rule.

In the example above, the getter and setter would provide the String `RPersonId` to turn into a property name. Since the first *two* characters are upper-case, the first character will not be lower-cased. As such, the property name that will be derived is `RPersonId`, and this explains your output.

You can also call the method [`decapitalize`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html#decapitalize-java.lang.String-) to see which property name would be located from a pair of getter / setter:

```
System.out.println(Introspector.decapitalize("RPersonId"));     // prints RPersonId
System.out.println(Introspector.decapitalize("PersonAddress")); // prints personAddress
```

Comment: How did you find this in the related specification documentation? Do you regularly dive deep into these? (It turns out that became helpful at this question) Is studying the JCP documents something a good developer should do? Thanks

Comment: RE: "However to support the occasional use of all upper-case names, we check if the first two characters of the name are both upper case and if so leave it alone."

Why only the first two characters? It is more correct to check all symbols.
This is a very strange decision.
I am getting similar error. The name for the "myData" field is correct, but for the "sData" field it is not.
I cannot change the names of the fields, it must match the name of the columns of the database table.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is part religion.

The people who did Java Beans felt that properties should ALWAYS be accessed by a pair of methods.  So you are NOT getting the name of the data member.  You are getting the property which can only be accessed by the methods.

This is from the documentation:

```
A PropertyDescriptor describes one property that a Java Bean exports 
via a pair of accessor methods.
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.html

The theory was you should never use the data member name, and so through the Bean interface, they don't give you that.

Comment: The answer doesn't explain why the first character was not lower-cased.

Comment: Thank you for response! 
That link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.html says that PropertyDescriptor has several constructors. Which one are invoked by calling getBeanInfo(this.getClass()).getPropertyDescriptors()?
It only says that if I create a PropertyDescriptor by myself, then I have to provide an getter/setter pair

Comment: @YuriyTsarkov When you're calling `Introspector.getBeanInfo`, you're relying on the introspector rules to get the propertydescriptor. They are the rules that I outlined [in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40822607/1743880) and you cannot change them. They explain your output.

Comment: @Tunaki, got it - just have tested your answer:) It's entirely true! Thank you!